# NPM package-lock query

Tags: node.js, npm

This is to get some clarification on the behaviour of npm with regards to package.json and package-lock.json.

The scenario is this, my package.json has an dependency like this:
"xxx-package" : "^7.34.0"

When I ran 'npm install' on a fresh machine (with no node_modules folder and no package-lock.json), the installer found a newer version of the package "7.36.0" and installed that instead. This is correct since we have the caret(^) sign in the dependency list.

But here is the confusing part: npm then created a package-lock.json with the new updated version but never changed the package.json listing. So now the package-lock.json shows "7.36.0" but package.json is still showing the lower version.

Also, 'npm outdated' and 'npm update' will not do anything since the version in package-lock matches the latest.

My app ran fine on "7.34.0" but a fresh install breaks it, and I spent a lot of time trying to fix a possible bug in my app. Only when I checked the package-lock did I realize that this was due to a newer version and not my code.

Is there a way to make sure package.json is updated whenever a new version gets installed using 'npm install'?
Or are we doing something wrong ?

npm version is 7.9.0
node version is 15.3.0

Comment: I think, it only updates the package.json, when, installing a specific package. So, when there is a package name behind `npm install`. I wonder, what would happen, if you would try `npm install --save`.

Comment: Tried that, same behavior. There is still a difference in version.

Comment: Just to make sure, since you added something to your question. The 7.36.0 version broke your app? Or did the fact, that the versions in package.json and package-lock.json were different, break your app?

Comment: The version update broke it. Using the command 'npm install xxx-package@7.34.0' fixes the issue.
For now removing the caret sign works for us as it causes the version to be enforced.

Comment: Then you don't want to have a way of updating the package.json, because that would just cause the same problem again. Seems like the best way is to stick to enforcing the version for now.